# Remove DNS from device using `nmcli`

Tags: linux, dns, networkmanager

I want to remove the DNS currently associated to the device and add a new one using `nmcli`

So, if I do `nmcli device show eth0` I can see

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.2.2
```

If I do `sudo nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8"`
then I can see

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.2.2
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

but I want to remove the first one. How can I do it? If i try `sudo nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.dns ""` then the second one (`8.8.8.8`) is removed but the first one is still there.

My final goal is to set ONLY `8.8.8.8` (for example...)

**EDIT:**

I am a bit confused between `connection` and `device`.

For example, let's say that I had `10.0.2,2` and I had `8.8.8.8` using one of these two commands:

`nmcli connection modify netplan-eth0 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`

`nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`

Because it seems there is a device and then there is a connection bound to it, so I can modify the dns using one of these two commands.

Now, I can see:

Using `nmcli device show` I have in the result

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.2.2
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

but using `nmcli connection show netplan-eth0` I can see only

```
ipv4.dns:                               8.8.8.8
```

So, my problem now is that I can easily modify the only dns in the connection, that is `8.8.8.8` using one of the followin command:

`nmcli connection modify netplan-eth0 -ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`

`nmcli device modify eth0 -ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8`

BUT, I don't know how to remove the `10.0.2.2` that is showing only in the `device` but not in the `connection`.

BTW I did not set manually `10.0.2.2`, I suppose it was taken through `dhcp`. And for some motivation this dns is bound only to the `device` but not to the `connection`.

With these details the problem should be more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general way to modify the dns, look at the answer of missconfigured.

About the problem of the dns get through `netplan` or dhcp, I could remove them using the following command:

`nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes`

After that, I was able to remove the `10.0.2.2` dns.

Answer (score 0):

To the Answer,

The below command is able to remove the default DNS, but after restart NetworkManager, the default DNS comes back. How to make it permanent? Thanks.

```
nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

Comment: Hi, in that case, you should modify some files in `/etc`. It depends if you use `systemd`, or other system. Some hint are: look in `/etc/resolv.conf` (especially if it is a real file or a link), `/etc/netplan`, or `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, `/etc/systemd/network/*.network`

Also, the following man page can be helpful: `man systemd-resolved.service` and `man resolved.conf`. I can not be more specific, without knowing your system.